# How to set the owner of a Jenkins folder when creating it with a seeder job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I've written a seeder job using the [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) to create [folders](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin) with a predefined collection of jobs inside. I also use the [Ownership Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ownership+Plugin) to control which users get access to each folder.

Now I need the user who fired the seeder job to be assigned as the folder's primary owner.

I tried setting **"Assign job creators as owners"** configuration option, but the result I get is that the created folder's owner is `SYSTEM`.

[image]

Is there a way to set the primary owner of the folder programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to do this by getting the name of the current use as the `Cause` of the `currentBuild` variable and then assign it to the folder by using the `configure` step like so:

```groovy
user = currentBuild.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause)
folder("MyFolder") {
    configure { folder ->
        folder / 'properties' / 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.ownership.model.folders.FolderOwnershipProperty' / 'ownership' {     
            primaryOwnerId(user.getUserId())
            ownershipEnabled('true')
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can provide a less verbose way to do this I'll mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the folder's config XML to see how the information is stored:

```xml
<com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder plugin="cloudbees-folder@6.1.2">
    <!-- ... -->
    <properties>
    <!-- ... -->
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.ownership.model.folders.FolderOwnershipProperty plugin="ownership@0.10.0">
        <ownership>
        <ownershipEnabled>true</ownershipEnabled>
        <primaryOwnerId>admin</primaryOwnerId>
        <coownersIds class="sorted-set">
            <string>daspilker</string>
        </coownersIds>
        </ownership>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.ownership.model.folders.FolderOwnershipProperty>
    <!-- ... -->
    </properties>
    <!-- ... -->
</com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder>
```

Then you can use a [Configure Block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) to create that config with Job DSL.